# WPF Ribbon Control - Application Menu event?

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I'm looking for a suitable event to trigger on clicking on the Application Menu in the Ribbon. Ideally to capture it and suppress the application menu from appearing and call something else.

Answer (score 0):

To suppress, you should use override. That would be overriding the parent's method of performing any action, and you can call something else.

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) for `override`.

Otherwise, you can handle that Click event. This way, the code inside your Click event handler would execute and the default behaviour will be skipped. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click(v=vs.110).aspx) is the MSDN documentation for the click handler.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't see any event that gets fired for that Ribbon control - the MouseUp Event gets called on all surfaces of the Ribbon control except for the ApplicationMenu Button. Can you please clarify what it is that I need to do?